# No package 'rpm' found

Tags: cmake

While building createrepo_c on Ubuntu 22.04, I got the error:

```
createrepo_c/build$ cmake ..
-- Checking for module 'rpm'
--   No package 'rpm' found
```

I have rpm installed, but that apparently doesn't provide the includes.

All the other missing dependencies came up right away when searching SO, but I can't seem to find this one, nor can I guess the name, like `rpm-dev`. What do I need to install to be able to build?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually mentioned in the [Readme](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/createrepo_c#building) in the format `libname` (`link`) `yum install`/`apt install`

The rpm development libraries can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install librpm-dev
```

and the full package can be built in Ubuntu 20.04 and newer with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y libbz2-dev cmake \
  libmagic-dev libglib2.0-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libxml2-dev libpython3-dev librpm-dev libssl-dev \
  libsqlite3-dev liblzma-dev zlib1g-dev libzstd-dev

git clone https://github.com/rpm-software-management/createrepo_c.git

mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. -DWITH_ZCHUNK=OFF -DWITH_LIBMODULEMD=OFF
make
./src/createrepo_c
```

but it is much easier on Ubuntu 22.04 to just install it:

```
sudo apt install createrepo-c
```